# Sass Работают ли переменные родительского sass файла в include

Tags: css, node.js, frontend, sass

У меня есть файл main.sass и screen.sass 
Screen.sass подключаю к main.sass через import

```
@import 'screen'
```

В main.css есть переменная

```
$green: #5dca88
```

Я вот так использую эту переменную в screen.sass :

```
border-top: 1px solid $green
```

Но почему то получается ошибка:
 sass\screen.sass

```
Error: Undefined variable: "$green".
        on line 26 of sass/screen.sass
>>      border-top: 1px solid $green;
```

Пробывала всавлять импорт и до обьявления переменной и после - ничего не помогает
 Подскажите что я делаю не так? Как сделаь что бы во внутрених файлах можно было использовать переменные из родительского файла?

Comment: Не понятно, подключаете `css` в `css`,  а в ошибке `sass` файл. Так что же вы в итоге используете?

Comment: Подключаю sass. Уже исправила в вопросе

Comment: попробуйте переименовать `screen.sass` в `_screen.sass`  и после в файле `main.sass` сначала обьявить переменную, а после сделать импорт.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло